# Modificar css de elemento dentro de iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Tengo un iframe con id="myframe" que tiene de fuente otro archivo del mismo servidor

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="referencia.php">

</iframe>
```

En referencia.php tengo un div con id="cuadro" que quiero que cuando se abre directamente el archivo referencia php sea visible, pero que en "myframe" no aparezca. He intentando con jquery lo siguiente pero no me ha funcionado

```
$('#myframe').$('#cuadro').css({'display':'none'});
```

o

```
$('#myframe').contains('#cuadro').css({'display':'none'});
```

Comment: Luis Carlos ,añadió una respuesta como comentario , solucionó su problema ? o aún persiste.

Answer (score 3):

**`Si está dentro del mismo servidor`**  una forma de hacerlo sería añadiendo un `tag`  al `body` del documento o página que carga en el `iframe` con las reglas css respectivas que desee para este caso el `display: none` para el `div` con id `#cuadro` . Sí es una página externa no podrá realizarse ya que con esto se protege de los típicos ataques [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Recuerde que debe acceder al contenido con `contents` , posteriormente buscar *(find)* el elemento `head` para ahí añadir el `style` tag

```
$('#myframe').contents().find("head")
   .append($("<style type='text/css'>  #cuadro{display:none;}  </style>"));
```